# INSERT INTO with embedded apostrophe

Tags: java, sqlite

Eclipse neon.1 (4.6.1) java;
SQLite 3.8.7 (sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar)

I am attempting to insert customer's data into a table using the following code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement ps;
insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_TotalPatent "
    + "(Abstract, `Application/Filing Date`, `Application Number`) "
    + "VALUES ("
    +  "'" + _field[0] + "', "
    +  "'" + _field[1] + "', "
    +  "'" + _field[2] + "');";
ps = con.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
ps.execute();
```

Unfortunately, the client's data has an embedded apostrophe, which I cannot change.  The "INSERT INTO" statement bombs out when finding the apostrophe, assuming it is a single quote:

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "s": syntax error)

I've tried various permutations of the INSERT INTO statement to use different characters for the single quote - to no avail.
I presume there is an "easy" work-around, but I can't find it.  The solution is probably posted somewhere on *stack**overflow***, but I can't find it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You use parameterized SQL, basically. Stop putting your values directly into your SQL, for readability, security, performance and simplicity reasons. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace that apostrophe with an double apostrophe, which is the standard SQL escape sequence for '

simply do that whith the following snippet:

```
+  "'" + _field[x].replaceAll("'", "''") + "', "
```

You could also use " instead of ' in your sql statement like the following:

```
+  "\"" + _field[x] + "\", "
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried using replace, but not .replaceALL.  That took care of the problem.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: i'm glad that it works now. i would appreciate a upvote :)